# On Win7 do I need WinDefender's scan when I have NOD32?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, windows-defender, nod32

I have NOD32 Antivirus which provides realtime virus protection and also, I think, does scheduled full-system checks now and then.

But the stock 'flag' icon (I don't know what it's called) in my systray is telling me that I'd better scan with WinDefender as well:

[image: WinDefender]

**Is this really necessary? If not, how do I disable the flag icon's warning?**

Comment: It's not really necessary, if you keep NOD32 updated it should catch the same viruses as Microsoft does. Just google to find instructions to disable the warning.

Comment: Usually 3rd party anti-virus programs disable Windows Defender automatically. I'm surprised that NOD32 didn't. By the way, how come you're still using Windows 7? You've got 8 days to either stay with Windows 7 or upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Windows Defender on Windows 7 is a malware scanner.  Nod32 is Anti-Virus.  If I were still using Windows 7 I would want a malware scanner to exist on my computer.  I wish I could, downvote comments, because people saying Windows Defender should automatically be disabled when Nod32 do not realize that Windows Defender on Windows 7 is not the same feature as Windows Defender on Windows 8 and above.

Comment: @monov - It being necessary is something only you can decide.  All I can say, is that Nod32, is not designed to find malware. That is the reason programs designed specifically to find malware exists.  How you disable the flag is simply, you perform a scan, by default the scan should happen automatically because of a schedule task that exists by default.

Comment: @Ramhound: Viruses are a kind of malware.

Comment: @Ramhound: Also note that [NOD32's site](http://www.eset.com/us/products/nod32-antivirus/) says "Antivirus and antispyware proactively detect and eliminate threats such as viruses, Trojans and spyware." when you hover the icon next to "Block viruses and hackers".

Comment: @monov I don't care what Nod32 claims it is, I have used it with Windows Defender, when i Ran Windows  7 for years.  The choice is yours, no reason to give up, free protection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to disable WinDefender (both realtime protection and scheduled scans), as I know it only protects against non-virus malware, and according to this quote from [NOD32's site](http://www.eset.com/us/products/nod32-antivirus/) NOD32 covers non-virus malware too:

> Antivirus and antispyware proactively detect and eliminate threats such as viruses, Trojans and spyware.

(it says this when you hover the icon next to "Block viruses and hackers")

I'll still welcome answers from more knowledgeable people.